# How do I convert every element of an array of strings to a number subject to certain conditions?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, integer

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings -- they could take any form.  I want to apply a "to_i" function to them, but only if the string only consists of numbers.  I tried this

```
data.map(&:to_i)
```

but this converts things like ["6M"] to ["6"], which I dont' want (I want it to be ["0"] since there is an "M" in there).  Then I tried

```
 data.select{|string| string.to_i.to_s == string ? string.to_i : -2 }
```

but this too does nothing.  How can I convert strings to integers subject to certain conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were one step from solution. One should still use `map`, not `select` there:

```
%w|6M 6 M|.map { |s| (i = s.to_i).to_s == s ? i : 0 }
#⇒ [0, 6, 0]
```

Another way would be to make use of `Regexp`:

```
%w|6M 6 M|.map { |s| s =~ /\A-?\d+\z/ ? s.to_i : 0 }
#⇒ [0, 6, 0]
```

Comment: As a slight variation, how about `data.map { |s| s.match?(/\D/) ? 0 : s.to_i }`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 negatives

Answer (score 0):

I think, one of a possible solutions is:

```
a = %w|6m 6 m|
a.map { |e| Integer(e) rescue 0 }
#=> [0, 6, 0]
```